# Read profile variable from batch file and echo in command for autosys windows

Tags: batch-file, autosys

i have autosys job like below

```
insert_job: job_name
command: cmd /c path/abc.bat
machine:
owner:
permission: 
std_out_file:
std_err_file:
profile: "profile.bat"
```

in profile.bat file there i have set variable

```
SET name=""
SET mydate=""
```

how to echo date from profile:bat file in command after invoke bat command

Comment: Which command,where do you need date in command

Comment: In autosys command I want date to run batch file on particular date

Comment: you can save the date present in batch-file in a file and then read that file in autosys.

Comment: How to read from file?

Comment: i dunno about autosys but [this](https://community.broadcom.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MID=762792#bm38ecd8d4-5130-43a3-ad4b-a0806bb06c2a) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to store batch file of profile attribute in same remote machine.

Comment: This is not an answer, maybe edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709551/edit